# Do mitochondrial DNA have repair enzymes?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, dna, mitochondria, dna-damage

Mitochondria are considered endosymbionts originated from a prokaryote. So, do they have a DNA repair mechanism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mtDNA can be repaired by enzymes coded by nuclear genes.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22992591

Comment: Could you provide a brief synopsis of this review article for future reference when others come to find this question?